# If else not working on the basis of user selection

Tags: java, servlets, forms

I am working on HTML tables. For that I am returning JSON from my Java code. I have a UI as HTML page where there is a form having from date to date and a select tag having 4 options like this

```
 <form id="formId" method="get">
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Start Date:</h4>
            <input type="text" id="startdate" name="fromdate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />

            <h4>End Date:</h4>
            <input type="text" id="enddate" name="todate" width="276"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required />


            <h4>Outlets:</h4>
            <select name="outlet" id="all">
                <option>ALL</option>
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.outlet}">
                    <option>${item}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>

            <br>

            <br>
            <div>

                <button id="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>

        </div>
</form>
```

I am taking that input from the form and  getting values in the servlet in doget method like below:

```
    String fromdate=request.getParameter("fromdate");
        String todate=request.getParameter("todate");
        String outlet=request.getParameter("outlet");

//      System.out.println(String.format("fromdate: %s, todate: %s, outlet: %s", new Object[]{fromdate, todate, outlet}));
        List<String> outletList = Arrays.asList(outlet.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        try {
            String json = HourlySalesDateOutlet.createJson(outletList, fromdate, todate);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
//          System.out.println("dheeraj"+json);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Now here is my Java class where I have written two queries one for if the user selects all and other if user select specific outlet. My problem is the if statement is not executing only else is executing if the user selects one outlet from FORM if the user selects ALL then it's not working.

Below is my code:

```
   public static String createJson(List<String> outletList, String startDate, String endDate) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        String query1;
        List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
        String outletStr = outletList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "('", "')"));
        if (outletList.equals("ALL")) {
            query1 = "SELECT a.OUTLET,b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR,a.BILLDATE,HOUR(a.BILLTIME) AS HOURS, SUM(a.NETAMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM SYNCBILL a,ecustomer b WHERE a.OUTLET=b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER AND a.CANCELLED<>'Y' AND a.BILLDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('"
                    + startDate + "','/','.'),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) AND STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('" + endDate
                    + "','/','.'),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) GROUP BY OUTLET,BILLDATE,HOUR(BILLTIME)";
            System.out.println("all"+query1);

        } else {

            query1 = "SELECT a.OUTLET,b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR,a.BILLDATE,HOUR(a.BILLTIME) AS HOURS, SUM(a.NETAMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM SYNCBILL a,ecustomer b WHERE a.OUTLET=b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER AND b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR in "
                    + outletStr + " AND a.CANCELLED<>'Y' AND a.BILLDATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('" + startDate
                    + "','/','.'),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) AND STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('" + endDate
                    + "','/','.'),GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) GROUP BY OUTLET,BILLDATE,HOUR(BILLTIME)";
            System.out.println("2"+query1);
        }

        try {


            con = DBConnection.createConnection();


            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Map<RecordKey, Long> mapData = getMapList(rs);
        }
```

I am not posting the full Java code. What I want is if the user selects all then if statement should execute and the query in it should execute. If the user selects else, then other should work, and here in my code only else is working if is not executing.

How can I debug this?

Comment: you need to specify value for option tag `<option value="ALL">ALL</option>`

Comment: In your if statement you are comparing a List of Strings with a String: `outletList.equals("ALL")`. That is never returning true.

Comment: @MWB okk..so what i need to do?

Comment: @manishthakur First get the String from the list.

Comment: @MWB can you please help me with the code actually i am new to this so please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution for your problem. When user selects all, then in that case pass the empty list and while making the query just put this condition.

```
if (outletList.size()==0) {
// case for all
} else {
// do regular stuff
}
```

Comment: sir in both the cases its taking size as 1.. as i have printed on console outletList.size()..because on selecting ALL  the outletStrr  print 'ALL' on console

Comment: You need to change code while putting values in the list. If you receive ALL from html form, don't put anything in list and put only if the value received is not ALL

Comment: While this might end up being a single if/else, as your code grows and changes, you end up with an unknown number of potential if/if-else/else pairs that you'll have to maintain making it a risk and liability. The most blatant misuse, or lack of use,of logical constructs is when you codify differences between having none, one, or many, in a list of stuff.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: There are only two cases here to handle which can easily be handled by if else only. And it is your fault as a programmer if you misuse if else and spam them uselessly without giving a proper thought. Also, whenever someone tries to use if/else, do you tell the same story to them like you did here and discourage them from using if/else?

Comment: Beyond your recognition that "there are only two cases to handle..." ***now***, there is the fact that a list is a list, it has none, one, or many elements. And as you can profess uses of if/else if to deal with variants of this fact, you are without doubt proposing limited, risky, difficult to maintain solutions that are unnecessary as the data structure itself provides implicit operations to deal with such issues. For example, `for(blah, blah, blah)` implicitly deals with all possible situations that are known for a sizable collection.

Comment: Well, I would say, provide an elegant solution to OP and that's all is needed. I would be very happy to see that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you're not comparing comparable types. `outletList` is a `List` and it can't be equated to a `String` even though the list may only contain a single element that happens to be a `String`. So, `outletList.equals("ALL")` doesn't do what you think it does.

But that raises an interesting point. You have a select list which isn't `multiple` so why return a list of what is *always* a ***single*** value? And why switch to sending back an empty list when `ALL` is selected? That doesn't make sense; there was a single selection made as expected. This adds unnecessary confusion.

Try instead sending back the single value as a `String` and letting that value determine the logic so you have flexibility. If it's not possible to avoid the list then accept only a single value (`list[0]` for example) and call equals on *that* ***not*** the `List`.

`if(outletList[0].equals("All")) {...}`

If you later find yourself in a situation where you need more than a single `if-else` pair, you can switch to a `switch` like so:

```
switch(outletList[0]) { // or the single value...
    case "ALL":
        ...
    ...
    default:
        ... 
}
```